# What does the address of an lvalue reference to a prvalue represent?

Tags: c++, value-categories

When a function parameter is of type lvalue reference `lref`:

```
void PrintAddress(const std::string& lref) {
  std::cout << &lref << std::endl;
}
```

and `lref` is bound to a prvalue:

```
PrintAddress(lref.substr() /* temporary of type std::string */)
```

what does the address represent? What lives there?

A prvalue cannot have its address taken. But an lvalue reference *to* a prvalue *can* have its address taken, which is curious to me.

Comment: And is it legal (in C++, and with respect to memory) to write to that address? e.g., `const_cast<string&>(static_cast<cost string&>(s.substr(1))) = string()`

Comment: a temporary lives there. they have lifetime, and are sometimes mutable

Comment: "What lives there?" - huh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, because the prvalue's lifetime has been extended. By having its lifetime extended - by any reference -, it's an lvalue, and thus can have its address taken.

---

> what does the address represent? What lives there?

The address represents an object, the object referenced by `lref`.

A prvalue is short lived, it doesn't live for long. In fact, it will be destroyed when the statement creating it ends.

But, when you create a reference to a prvalue (either an rvalue reference or a const lvalue reference), its lifetime is extended. [Ref.:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue):

> An *rvalue* may be used to initialize a *const lvalue* [*rvalue*] reference, in which case the lifetime of the object identified by the *rvalue* is **extended until the scope of the reference ends**.

Now it makes actually sense to take its address, as it is an lvalue for all intents and purposes. Now, that the prvalue has an indeterminate lifetime, it is an lvalue.

Taking the address of a prvalue doesn't make sense however, and that's probably why it is disallowed:

- The value is destroyed after the next statements, so you can't do anything with the address, except maybe print it out.
- If you take the address of something, the compiler is required to actually create the object. Sometimes, the compiler will optimize out variables that are trivial, but if you were to take the address of them, the compiler won't be allowed to optimize them out.

  Taking the address of a prvalue will thus result in the compiler being unable to elide the value completely, for no advantages whatsoever (see point 1).

Comment: Upvotes all around, but I think this wins for the bullet points explaining possible motivations for *why* it makes sense to take the address of `lref` but not a `prvalue`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Inside the function `lref` is not a prvalue it is an lvalue and you can take the address of it.

There is a common misconception about rvalues vs. lvalues.
A named parameter is always an lvalue. No matter whether it is a reference type that is bound to an rvalue. Through a `const &` reference type you can't even tell which kind of value category the object actually has at the point where the function is called. Rvalue references and non-const Lvalue references give you that information:

```
void foo(std::string& L, std::string&& R)
{
    // yeah i know L is already an lvalue at the point where foo is called
    // R on the other hand is an rvalue at the point where we get called
    // so we can 'safely' move from it or something...
}
```

The temporary string is a prvalue in the context of the caller (at the point `PrintAddress` is called). Within the context of the callee (in `PrintAddress`) `lref` is an lvalue reference because in this context it actually is an lvalue.

`PrintAddress` isn't aware of the limited lifetime of the passed argument and from `PrintAddress`' point of view the object is "always" there.

```
std::string q("abcd");
PrintAddress(q.substr(1)); // print address of temporary
```

is conceptually equivalent to:

```
std::string q("abcd");
{
    const std::string& lref = q.substr(1);
    std::cout << &lref << std::endl;
}
```

where the temporary experiences a prolongation of its lifetime to the end of the scope in which `lref` is defined (which is to the end of `PrintAddress` function scope in the present example).

---

> what does the address represent? What lives there?

A `std::string` object containing the passed content.

> And is it legal (in C++, and with respect to memory) to write to that address?

No, it would be legal if you'd use an rvalue reference:

```
void PrintAddressR(std::string&& rref) {
    rref += "Hello"; // writing possible
    std::cout << &rref << std::endl; // taking the address possible
}
// ...
PrintAddressR(q.substr(1)); // yep, can do that...
```

The same applies here: `rref` is an lvalue (it has a name) so you can take its address plus it is mutable.

Comment: Do you have a source for the modification being illegal? It makes sense that binding to a const reference would disqualify modifications, but I think there's a reasonable chance that's not the case. Why I say reasonable is because you can do things like call non-const member functions on prvalues.

Comment: So to be precise, would you say `lref` is **not** an `lvalue reference to prvalue`, but rather an `lvalue reference to const string, *initialized with* the prvalue`?

Comment: @chris: No, I haven't and I don't think that I can look it up in the standard just now but I don't think there is anything preventing the compiler from putting a temporary that is bound to a `const &` into special read only memory (especially for compile time constant things / literals) that shouldn't be touched.

Comment: I think [conv.rval] would cover this. *A prvalue of type T can be converted to an xvalue of type T.* The prvalue has type `std::string`, so the materialized xvalue object would have type `std::string` and would thus be modifiable. [dcl.init.ref] calls out materialization being applied when a prvalue is bound to a const reference. The background for this is that doing `std::string s; foo(s);` would allow `foo`'s const reference to cast away the const and modify it.

Comment: @mgiuffrida: No I'd say that `lref` is `reference to const string to which a prvalue is bound`.

Comment: I take it back. The type is adjusted to have `const` before materialization is applied.

Comment: @chris is this c++17 wizardry?

Comment: @mgiuffrida, I highly doubt it. Those rules should be pretty consistent since C++98.

Comment: @chris I mean your terminology (the term "materialization" as well as the [conv.rval] section). Which, it looks like N4606(5.2.2.2) might apply -- the `lref` is bound to the result of the `temporary materialization conversion` applied to the implicit conversion of the `prvalue` to `const T`. maybe. But N3485 just says the reference is bound to the "result of the initializer expression".

Comment: @mgiuffrida, Oh, I figured that term would have been there for  good while considering how an rvalue binds to a const reference hasn't really changed much from a user's point of view.

Answer (score 3):

In simple English:

```
void PrintAddress(const std::string& lref) {
  std::cout << &lref << std::endl;
}
```

Any object that has a name is an `lvalue`, hence any use of `lref` within the scope of the funtion above is an `lvalue` use.

When you called the function with:

```
PrintAddress(lref.substr() /* temporary of type std::string */)
```

Of cause, `lref.substr()` produces a temporary which is an `rvalue`, but `rvalues` can bind to (have its lifetime extended by) const lvalue references or rvalue references.

---

Even if you provided an `rvalue` overload, *for the fact it has a name*, its an *"lvalue of something"* within its scope, example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void PrintAddress(const std::string& lref) {
  std::cout << "LValue: " << &lref << std::endl;
}

void PrintAddress(std::string&& `rref`) {
  std::cout << "RValue: " << &rref << std::endl;  //You can take address of `rref`
}

int main(){
    std::string str = "Hahaha";
    PrintAddress(str);
    PrintAddress(str.substr(2));
}
```

---

Just remember:

> In C++, *any* object(whether *value type*, *reference type* or *pointer type*) that has a *name* is an *lvalue*

Also know that [some expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue) produce *lvalues* too.